# Keeping div's width same as wrapper, but making the background full width

Tags: css, html, background

The image shows what I'm trying to accomplish. All 3 divs are contained in a wrapper that's 800px. But the second div's background extends the full width of the body.

[image]

Comment: To get an effect like what you want might require some extra elements (pseudo-elements), would that be okay?

Comment: @MarcAudet Hi Marc, After posting the question, I played around with it a bit more and came up with a way to do it using extra divs, so if your way uses extra divs, that's OK with me. Basically my way is to remove the single outer wrapper and replace it with separate wrappers (in this case 3 because I need to break the page to stuff before the special div, stuff after the special div, and the special div itself). I'm interested to see your code, please post.

Comment: Your approach is similar to what I have used in the past for a similar problem.  I am trying something with some absolute elements.  If I get something decent, I will post it.  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution nearly identitical to the one by patkay.

My HTML:

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content">Content 1...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper noted">
        <div class="content">Content 2...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="content">Content 3...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.outer-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.inner-wrapper {
    width: inherit;
}
.inner-wrapper.noted {
    background-color: gray;
}
.content {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Nbu7G/

Essentially, I use the `.outer-wrapper` to set control the overall width, and then inherit the width to the `.inner-wrapper` which is used to set the background color through an extra class call `.noted`.

The inner-most container `.content` has the fixed width (for example, 600px).

The extra markup could be clean-up semantically using HTML5 tags, but this pattern gives you a lot of hooks to use background images and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is to have three separate div's that are all aligned centrally on the inside, have full width backgrounds and are stacked on top of each other.

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="mid">
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.top, .bottom {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
}

.mid {
  background: #616161;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I would not bother with text-align: center in the body tag, not needed, otherwise the solution is pretty good.